# Gesture Detection in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, gesturedetector

I have a **ListFragment** that I populate with a ContentProvider.

I need to attach a **gesture listener** to each of them so that when the user swipes to right, the item is removed from the list.

Below is all I have in my ListFragment at the moment.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

 String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), selection + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Log.d("TodoListFragment", selection+ "");

}
```

How would I attach the gesture detection and listening?

I have done some research and found this piece of code:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
               Log.d("Swipe", "Left");
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d("Swipe", "Right");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to implement it? (Not the deleting part but just the implementation)

Comment: You might wish to examine: https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/Fgo1p5uWZLu as this is one Googler's approach towards implementing swipe-to-remove in a `ListView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will definitely try that. Looks promising :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced some problem throughout i fixed issue using below answer.

it works perfectly.

```
class SideIndexGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            Log.d("Scrolled- fragment ", "Scrolling");
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                new SideIndexGestureListener());
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        getListView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        try {

           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, elementos);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```